# Построение алгоритма, с чего подступиться?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Как организовать алгоритм?

**Вот сама задача:**

[image: Головоломка]

На рисунке изображена головоломка, в которой цифры от 1 до 7 располагаются в ячейках, а одна из ячеек свободна.

Она используется для проверки интеллекта роботов. Для ее решения необходимо переставить цифры, используя свободную
ячейку, чтобы цифры расположились так, как показано на рисунке. Перемещение цифры в свободную ячейку возможно, только
если ячейки соединены линией. Напишите программу на java, которая определяет минимальное количество ходов для решения
головоломки. В решении необходимо реализовать интерфейс:

```
/**
* Интерфейс решения головоломки.
*/
public interface PuzzleResolver
{
/**
* Метод решения головоломки.
* @param start первоначальное состояние головоломки
* @return решение головоломки
*/
int[] resolve(int[] start);
}
```

На вход методу resolve передается массив чисел start, который содержит перестановку чисел 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 – начальную
позицию. Числа перечисляются в порядке чтения слева направо, сверху вниз. Число 0 обозначает пустую ячейку. Метод должен
вывести последовательность ходов – последовательность цифр от 1 до 7, которые нужно перемещать на очередном ходе в
свободную ячейку. Если существует несколько минимальных вариантов для последовательности ходов, то можно вывести любой
из них. Гарантируется, что все начальные позиции для головоломки имеют решение.

- **Пример 1**
- Ввод:
- 1 2 3 4 0 5 6 7
- Вывод:
- <пустой массив>
- **Пример 2**
- Ввод:
- 2 1 3 4 0 5 6 7
- Вывод:
- 5 3 2 1 2 3 5
- **Пример 3**
- Ввод:
- 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
- Вывод:
- 2 1 3 4 5 1 3 2 3 1 5 4 2 1 3 1 2 4

Comment: Навскидку - поиск в ширину. С генерацией вершин (состояний игры) на лету. Их никак не больше 8!=40320 :), что не так уж много...

Comment: Если не секрет, на какую должность претендуете?

Comment: Стажёр Java Developer, а что, что-то не так?)

Comment: @Nero да просто уже притча во языцех, когда компания на собеседовании парит такими задачами, а после найма приходится клепать CRUD'ы.

Comment: Чтобы быть Java developer надо уметь самому решать подобные задачи.

Comment: Я бы выделил, 2а аспекта - 1й выделить "центр симметрии" определить такие сочетания для которых переход в начальное состояние осуществляется "прокручиванием" цифр по внешнему циклу, 2й преобразование перестановки - последовательность действий которая из `2 1 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6`  переводит в `1 2 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6`. Извиняюсь за сумбурность.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробовал порешать задачку на C#.

Что понятно из задачи:

- У нас есть состояния, который описаны позициями 8 чисел в массиве
- У нас есть переходы между состояниями
- У нас есть начальное состояние и надо кратчайший путь до конечного

таким образом, нам надо реаоищовать поиск в ширину в графе, где узел - состояние, ребро - переход между состояниями.

Для начала, так как у нас всего 8 чисел от 0 до 7, нам не обязательно использовать для состояния массив. Не знаю, как в java, но в C# целое число - 4 байта, чего хватит для представления всех 8-циферных чисел. Итак, сперва пишу конвертеры из массива чисел в одно число и обратно

```
int FromState(int[] state)
{
    var ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        ret += state[i];
        ret *= 10;
    }
    return ret / 10;
}

int[] ToState(int source, int[] cache)
{
    for(var i=7; i>=0; i--)
    {
        cache[i] = source % 10;
        source /= 10;
    }
    return cache;
}
```

Далее, так как нам надо будет работать с переходами, нужно написать функцию, которая примет состояние (из за соображений эффективности по памяти, я это состояние буду принимать как массиа чисел) и вернет набор соседей для этого состояния - то есть состояния, куда можно перейти из текущего состояния.

```
int[] swap (int[] inp, int i, int j)
{
    var tmp = inp[i];
    inp[i] = inp[j];
    inp[j] = tmp;
    return inp;
}

int GetSibling(int[] inp, int i, int j)
{
    var ret = FromState(swap(inp, i, j));
    swap(inp, i, j);
    return ret;     
}

IEnumerable<int> GetSiblings(int[] state)
{
    int ind = Array.IndexOf(state, 0);

    switch(ind){
        case 0:
            yield return GetSibling(state, 0, 1);               
            yield return GetSibling(state, 0, 2);
            break;

        case 1:
            yield return GetSibling(state, 1, 0);               
            yield return GetSibling(state, 1, 2);               
            yield return GetSibling(state, 1, 3);               
            break;

        case 2:
            yield return GetSibling(state, 2, 0);               
            yield return GetSibling(state, 2, 1);               
            yield return GetSibling(state, 2, 5);               
            break;

        case 3:
            yield return GetSibling(state, 3, 1);               
            yield return GetSibling(state, 3, 4);               
            yield return GetSibling(state, 3, 6);               
            break;

        case 4:
            yield return GetSibling(state, 4, 3);               
            yield return GetSibling(state, 4, 5);               
            break;

        case 5:
            yield return GetSibling(state, 5, 2);               
            yield return GetSibling(state, 5, 4);               
            yield return GetSibling(state, 5, 7);               
            break;

        case 6:
            yield return GetSibling(state, 6, 3);
            yield return GetSibling(state, 6, 7);               
            break;

        case 7:
            yield return GetSibling(state, 7, 6);
            yield return GetSibling(state, 7, 5);
            break;
    }       
}
```

Остается последнее - выполнить поиск в ширину. Я сделал его 3 циклами, но можно и 2мя обойтись, просто мне так больше нравится. Также в конце функции, после поиска, я просто посстанавливаю путь от найденного конца в начало.

```
public int[] resolve(int[] start)
{       
    var cache = new int[8];
    var first = FromState(start);
    var q = new Queue<int>();
    var visited = new HashSet<int>();
    var path = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    var end = 12340567;
    if (first == end) return new int[0];        

    q.Enqueue(first);
    visited.Add(first);

    while(q.Count > 0)
    {
        var len = q.Count;
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            var curr = q.Dequeue();
            var curState = ToState(curr, cache);
            foreach(var s in GetSiblings(curState))
            {
                if (visited.Contains(s)) continue;
                visited.Add(s);
                q.Enqueue(s);
                path[s]=curr;

                if (s == end)
                {
                    i=len;
                    q.Clear();
                    break;
                }
            }               
        }           
    }       

    var route = new Stack<int>();
    var cache1 = new int[8];
    var cache2 = new int[8];        
    var c = end; 

    while(c != first)
    {
        var prev = path[c];
        ToState(c, cache1);
        ToState(prev, cache2);          
        int ind = Array.IndexOf(cache1, 0);     
        route.Push(cache2[ind]);            
        c = prev;
    }       

    return route.ToArray();         
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", resolve(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7 })));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", resolve(new[] { 2, 1, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7 })));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", resolve(new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 })));
```

Вывод

```
// пусто
5 3 2 1 2 3 5
2 1 3 4 5 1 2 3 2 1 5 4 2 3 1 3 2 4
```

Последний ответ не сходится с вашим, оставляю вам найти причину этого, я просто хотел показать пример, как пожно попробовать решить задачу.

Comment: Перевёл код на java, второй вывод совпал, третий не совпал ни с выводом из примера, ни с вашим. На сколько я понял, не работает потому что число, которое хранит состояние, не может иметь 0 первой цифрой, соответственно любые состояния с первым нулём будут стираться на 1 символ. Буду разбираться)

Comment: @Nero с ведущим нулем всё отлично, вы не видите его так как ведущие нули никто не пишет, потому число `1234567` будет успешно преобразовано в массив `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7`