# Поиск в ширину с кратчайшем путем java

Tags: c#, return, ienumerable, yield

Вопрос по существующей задаче [Построение алгоритма, с чего подступиться?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/952833/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)
@Nero Вопрос такой, чем заменить конструкцию yield return для реализации в java, нужно самому реализовать Iterable?

```
c#
IEnumerable<int> GetSiblings(int[] state)
{
    int ind = Array.IndexOf(state, 0);

    switch(ind){
        case 0:
            yield return GetSibling(state, 0, 1);               
            yield return GetSibling(state, 0, 2);
            break;
---
```

Comment: непонятно, поясните

Comment: @michael_best в этой задаче https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/952833/Построение-алгоритма-с-чего-подступиться предоставлен код решения на c#, в нем есть конструкция "yield return" которая, насколько я понимаю добавляет в коллекцию IEnumerable первый элемент из метода GetSibling. Я хочу узнать какую аналогичную языковую конструкцию можно использовать в java для заполнения этой коллекции.Искал в гугле, но насколько понял в c# за работу yield return отвечает компилятор, и подробностей в исходниках c# так же не нашел.

Comment: Объявите в начале функции коллекцию целых чисел (например, `ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList();`), вместо каждого из yield добавляйте в коллекцию то, что под этим yield стоит (`yield return GetSibling(state, 0, 1); ==> myArray.Add(GetSibling(state, 0, 1));`, в конце функции верните вашу коллекцию (`return myArray;`). Имейте ввиду, что из за создания коллекции эффективность алгоритма может измениться. За точность кода не отвечаю, пишу с телефона, но идея должна быть понятна. Это самый простой вариант, возможно, есть лучше способ перевода на джаву, так что на ваш страх и риск :)

Comment: @tym32167 пробовал, но ArrayList<Integer> , как и списки, и сеты. Отказываются заполнятся при дальнейшем использовании алгоритма. Возможно в нем и проблема.

Comment: Так они в дальнейшем а алгоритме и не меняются, или я не понял что вы имеете ввиду